# How does a nuclear powered rocket engine work?

Tags: rocketry, nuclear-engineering, nuclear-technology

Nuclear power always require some way of converting the energy from nuclear to electrical or mechanical to be useful. For example, in a nuclear power generation facility, this is done through heat/steam which drives mechanical generators. What is the mechanism used to convert nuclear energy to rocket power?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Nuclear Thermal Rockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_thermal_rocket) (NTRs)

> the heat from a nuclear reaction replaces the chemical energy of the propellants in a chemical rocket. In an NTR, a working fluid, usually liquid hydrogen, is heated to a high temperature in a nuclear reactor and then expands through a rocket nozzle to create thrust. The external nuclear heat source theoretically allows a higher effective exhaust velocity and is expected to double or triple payload capacity compared to chemical propellants that store energy internally.